# how hive query is executed in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform, bigdata

I need to know how is hive query executed on distributed system like Hadoop. I have checked other questions but none of them explained in detail.

I am looking for the full execution process. As in I want to know why hive join queries are taking more time than simple select query.

Anyone who is aware of the hive execution process, please explain.

PS: I am using hortonworks data platform as Hadoop framework.

Comment: If anyone can provide link for good documentation for hive query process will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

User submitted SQL query is converted by Hive to physical operator tree which is optimized and converted to Tez Jobs and is then executed on Hadoop cluster. Distributed SQL query processing in Hadoop differs from conventional relational query engine when it comes to handling of intermediate result sets. Hive query processing often requires sorting and reassembling of intermediate result set; this is called shuffling in Hadoop parlance.

Most of the existing query optimizations in Hive are about minimizing shuffling cost. Currently user would have to submit an optimized query to Hive with right join order for query to be executed efficiently. Logical optimizations in Hive are limited to filter push down, projection pruning and partition pruning. Cost based logical optimizations can significantly improve Apache Hive’s query latency and ease of use.

Join reordering and join algorithm selection are few of the optimizations that can benefit from a cost based optimizer. Cost based optimizer would free up user from having to rearrange joins in the right order or from having to specify join algorithm by using query hints and configuration options. This can potentially free up users to model their reporting and ETL needs close to business process without having to worry about query optimizations.

Read the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Cost-based+optimization+in+Hive), it's got what you're after.  If you have a specific question about code, post what you have tried and what you are hoping to achieve.